# Can I progressively load a page that has lots of PDF fies on it?

Tags: pdf

I have a page that has 41 individual PDF pages on it, does the progressive load plugins load each PDF as it becomes visible?

The original issue was that with all pages in one PDF the page was 8MB in size and took to long to load so I have broken up the PDF into individual pages.

Comment: Maybe convert pdf to html instead?

Comment: You'll have to check with the individual plugin developers themselves to see what their plugin does.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.